# Finding the nearest XY coordinates

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

I've got a point in 2d image for example the red Dot in the given picture and a set of n points blue dot (x1,y1)...(xn,yn) and I want to find nearest point to (x0,y0) in a way better than trying all points. Like to have best possible solution. Would appreciate if you share any similar class if you have.

[image]

Comment: Do you know anything about the image? Because if you do not, then all you can really do is search your 1 distance neighbors, then 2 distance, and so on. So do you know more information such as where the blue dot might be, or something like that? Without that information you're forced to do a brute force search. Does the blue dot only exist on one side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most solutions that we could suggest would depend on a little bit more knowledge, I am going to go out on a limb and say that unless you already know that you are short on time. I.e. there are tens of thousands of blue dots or you have to do thousands of these calculations in a short time. "[Linear Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#Linear_search)" will serve you well enough.

Don't bother calculating the actual distance, save yourself calculating the square root and use this as the "distance".

Most other methods use more complex data structures to sort the points in respect to their geometric arrangement. But are a lot harder to implement.

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches to this, the most common probably being using some form of space partitioning to speed up the search so that it is not O(n).  For details, see [Nearest neighbor search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) on Wikipedia.